# jQuery Form Wizard not submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a form through the jQuery Form Wizard and its not posting into the database. Am a novice of js but trying to find my way out to just get this done.

My issue is that the POST data doesnt get to the database.
On `submit` I have put the below code to send the data to the database.

This is my js code

```
$('#form_wizard_1').bootstrapWizard({
    'nextSelector': '.button-next',
    'previousSelector': '.button-previous',
    onTabClick: function (tab, navigation, index, clickedIndex) {
        success.hide();
        error.hide();
        if (form.valid() == false) {
            return false;
        }
        handleTitle(tab, navigation, clickedIndex);
    },
    onNext: function (tab, navigation, index) {
        success.hide();
        error.hide();

        if (form.valid() == false) {
            return false;
        }

        handleTitle(tab, navigation, index);
    },
    onPrevious: function (tab, navigation, index) {
        success.hide();
        error.hide();

        handleTitle(tab, navigation, index);
    },
    onTabShow: function (tab, navigation, index) {
        var total = navigation.find('li').length;
        var current = index + 1;
        var $percent = (current / total) * 100;
        $('#form_wizard_1').find('.progress-bar').css({
            width: $percent + '%'
        });
    }
});

$('#form_wizard_1').find('.button-previous').hide();
$('#form_wizard_1 .button-submit').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url:'reg_post.php',
        data:$('#submit_form').serialize(),
        data : { appraiseid : $("#appraiseid").val() },
        type:'POST',
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $(".alert-success").show().fadeOut(5000);
        },
        error:function(data){
            $(".alert-danger'").show().fadeOut(5000);
        }
    });
}).hide();
```

Php:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("church",$conn); 
if(!empty($_POST['userename'])) { 
    $appraisename = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["userename"]));
} 
$form1sql = "INSERT INTO reg (username) VALUES('".$appraisename."') ";
mysql_query($form1sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
?>
```

html:

Its a long form but trying to post one field first. Then can move on from there.
The HTML & JS works fine. its just to post into the database.

Comment: This is the php post script
<?php
 $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
   mysql_select_db("church",$conn);

if(!empty($_POST['appraisename'])) {
    $appraisename = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["appraisename"]));
}

$form1sql = "INSERT INTO reg (name)
            VALUES('".$appraisename."') ";
    mysql_query($form1sql) or die(mysql_error());
?>

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: You're not doing *any* error checking of your database connection. Add error checking, such as `or die(mysql_error())` to your connection. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Comment: i dont think the script is getting to my php script cos i dont get any error. The submit will only click but nothing happens.

Comment: You need to look at your browser's console for errors concerning the JavaScript/jQuery

Comment: Its not from my browser.....Ive checked That

Comment: Then we would be at a loss. With no errors in your browser and no error on your server there is nothing that is obvious from what you've posted. You *are* accessing this from a web server, right?

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: Pls should i add a little of the html form into the code? maybe that will help.

Comment: Yes, add the markup for the form.

Comment: Pls am new here and cant paste the form as i get an error which i try the ctrl+k thats required but to no avail. So sorry to disturb, pls help.

Comment: Did you click 'edit'?

Comment: Ive added a link u can use to view the form. Pls check and possibly view the source code.Thanks

Comment: Oops! Thanks a bunch......really appreciate your effort.

Comment: Yikes! That is a huge form. Posting all of that would not be relevant to the question. Perhaps you should start with a smaller form and work through the issues, then add to it a little at a time.

Comment: Please av u checked the link i added now to view the form?

Comment: I have viewed the form, that is how I determined that it was way too large to post here.

Comment: Ok. Dou, i tried reducing it by posting relevant parts buh seem its still kinda long. So pls what am i am missing out?

Comment: You're going to have to start small, as I mentioned before.

Comment: yes thats what i did with the php script but i notice the js is not getting to the php script which was included in the js script.

Comment: Do yourself a favor, simply place a `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)` in the PHP page which receives the form submission. Fill out your form, submit and look closely at the data that gets printed to the screen. Familiarize yourself with how form data is posted to scripts, including what gets passed and what doesn't.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Nothing happens, the submit button still will not respond. I believe theres something to be done on the js scprit. The js is not passing to the PHP script at all.

Comment: I only get Javascript:; at the bottom of my browser.

Comment: i tried something now and its posting into d db but its empty. only my id which is a_i is showing. Pls what can i do again?

Comment: You have to check that you're sending all of your form inputs to the PHP script.

Comment: Am only trying to post the first field with PHP but i made sure i fill all the forms as they are required.

Comment: Pls am still getting empty post into my db. Pls help figure out what the problem is. Thanks a bunch

Comment: We have reached a point where I cannot help you. Without being able to see errors and without having the full code available it would be impossible for us to track down the errors in your code.

Comment: If you wont mind, i can mail you the html, php and js scripts so you can have a full view. I really do appreciate your effort, time and concern.

Comment: Wahoo...Done it now. I got my data in the db now. I comment  the //data : { appraiseid : $("#appraiseid").val() }, and it works. Thanks so much.